# OpenCart 2.3.0.2 - Where did my bad extension go?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module, opencart2.3

I am experimenting to make a new extension in my OpenCart 2.3.02, and I did a mistake in the code.
Now my admin panel will not load at all, just a white page - and I cant remove the extension the normal way.

The file must be somewhere on the server, but I can't find it. Could anyone tell me where they go?

Comment: Delete all code which you did...

Comment: How do you think that is going to help me when I cant upload new code?

Comment: tell me in brief what you did?

Comment: I installed my extension the normal way, through the extension installer in the admin panel. Then after refreshing the modifications all pages are blank. I can't reach any pages at all anymore, and thus I can't upload or reinstall anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember , backup first

Go to system/storage/modification and delete all files and folder, it will load your site temporarily until you clear and rebuild cache from extension install / modification.

Comment: Correct!
I found out myself just before this answer was posted, after comparing files in a fresh install with a faulty install. 
The solution is confirmed with testing.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1.Go to admin/controller/extension/module and delete your created extension file.

2.Go to admin/language/en-gb/extension/module and delete your created extension file.

3.Go to admin/view/template/extension/module and delete your created extension file.

4.Go to catalog/controller/extension/module and delete your created extension file.

5.Go to catalog/language/en-gb/extension/moduleand delete your created extension file.

6.Go to catalog/view/template/extension/module  and delete your created extension file.

i think its helpful for you to fix error...

Comment: 1: There are no files at this location, and nothing that seems related to my extension.
2: That path does not exist, and no related files or folders are found.
3: The folder contains no related files.
4: That path does not exist, and no related files or folders are nearby.
5: That path does not exist, and no related files or folders are nearby.
6: That path does not exist, and no related files or folders are nearby.

Comment: but this is basic file directory of opencart...when we create new extension or  default extension.

Comment: None of the extensions I have installed are located in any of the above directories. Are you sure you are talking about 2.3.0.2?